# Firebase database Data Swift

Tags: ios, swift, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, firebase-security

1. How do I access database data and put it into a string variable (Swift)?

   - How would I just access the username of the current user logged in? For example: retrieve the current users Username in the JSON tree below.

     [image: JSON Tree Image]

---

```
{
    "rules": {
        "Users":{
            ".read": "true",
            ".write": "true"
        }
    }
}
```

---

```
let currentUser = FIRAuth.auth()?.currentUser
let ref = FIRDatabase.database().reference()
```

2. How do I make a new set of rules that adds Current Messages. For example: a chat room that will represent all of the messages sent? How can I add on to the current rules without affecting the Users or the rest of the data?

Comment: first, read the documentation and try it for yourself and ask a question here if you're stuck somewhere or have any query.

Comment: I have been trying it my self for an hour now and I cant see it figure it out.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With this code you can get the currently logged in username

```
    let userID = FIRAuth.auth()?.currentUser?.uid
    ref.child("users").child(userID!).observeSingleEvent(of: .value, with: {     (snapshot) in

    let snapDict = snapshot.value as? NSDictionary

    let username = snapDict?["username"] as? String ?? ""
    print(username)
    })
```

For further references please go through this link https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/ios/read-and-write

Comment: Thank you for getting me on my feet. I had something close but this pointed me in the right direction you are much apreciated!